# Button not appear after map display

Tags: css

I have a code with map and some buttons.  I want to make the map cover whole screen width. The map is covering the whole width but the buttons should appear below the map which is not at the moment.

Can anybody tell me what I have done wrong?

```js
var myloc = new L.LatLng(13.7433242, 100.5421583);
var map = L.map('map').setView(myloc, 12);

L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
  maxZoom: 18,
  id: 'mapbox.streets',
  accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1Ijoic2FuaW5kcmEiLCJhIjoiY2pqam5qZzZnMHRycTNrbWR3ZGF4Mmd5eSJ9.ZRIVhopMmACa80OQ0yZN3g'
}).addTo(map);
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

#map {
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="map"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <input type="button" id="btn-first" class="btn-a" value="First">
      <input type="button" id="btn-second" class="btn-a" value="Second">
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: do you want it inside the map or outside of the map?

Comment: @Viira outside map

Comment: Check my answer hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go! 
This might help you.

I've added a class to the buttons and made it `position:absolute;` + `bottom:0;` which brought them down. I hope it helps you.

```js
var myloc = new L.LatLng(13.7433242, 100.5421583);
var map = L.map('map').setView(myloc, 12);

L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
  maxZoom: 18,
  id: 'mapbox.streets',
  accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1Ijoic2FuaW5kcmEiLCJhIjoiY2pqam5qZzZnMHRycTNrbWR3ZGF4Mmd5eSJ9.ZRIVhopMmACa80OQ0yZN3g'
}).addTo(map);
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

#map {
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  clear: both;
}
 /*this is what I've added*/
.btns{bottom:0; position:absolute;}
 /*this is what I've added*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="map"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row btns">
      <input type="button" id="btn-first" class="btn-a" value="First">
      <input type="button" id="btn-second" class="btn-a" value="Second">
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: not a good solution, imagine when `div.container` has more and more content in it !

Comment: Then I'll came with the different solution, I write codes based on the structure of the HTML!!!!!!!! @ths

Comment: yup, the structure is the same I think you meant content ?

Answer (score 1):

```
#map {
height: 200px;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
clear: both;
}
```

This works nicely..

Comment: yes I have tried add z-index.. But the button appear on top of map . I need to show them below the map

Comment: @SS, I have updated my code..Make it position:relative and set a height value...This works fine.

Comment: nope its not working . I want map to cover whole width of the screen and button should appear after the map below

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.row:nth-child(2) {
    margin-top: 80%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Updated code as per your comment "yes I have tried add z-index.. But the button appear on top of map . I need to show them below the map"

jsfiddle.net/1bwmyhvd/4

HTML:-

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row map-block">
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <input type="button" id="btn-first" class="btn-a" value="First">
  <input type="button" id="btn-second" class="btn-a" value="Second">
</div>
```

added extra class for map parent row.

CSS:-

```
.map-block{
   position:relative;
   min-height:200px;
}

#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  clear: both;
  z-index: -1;
}
```